# Display taxonomy loop using custom field data

Tags: custom-field, post-type

Just learning PHP. Wondering what I'm doing wrong here.

The aim is: if custom field in taxonomy term (in "shows" taxonomy) has data, show posts loop of taxonomy term in a custom post type ("blogs"). The field data has the name of the desired taxonomy term. My code is returning all the posts in the post type instead of my specified term. I was also convinced I limited the post count to 2, but that changed up on me for some reason and it's displaying infinite posts.

```
<?php
$news = get_field('news', $term);
if ( $news ) {
    ?>
    <h2 class="showhead">News & Upcoming Shows</h2>
    <?php
    $custom_terms = get_terms('show-blogs');
    foreach ( $custom_terms as $custom_term ) {
        wp_reset_query();
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'blogs',
            'posts_per_page' => 2,
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'show-blogs',
                    'field' => $news,
                    'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
                    'posts_per_page' => 2,
                ),
            ),
        );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $loop->have_posts()) {
                $loop->the_post();
                ?>
                <table style="border:none;border: none;max-width: 50%;float: left;">
                    <tr>
                        <td rowspan="2" style="border:none;width: 113px;">
                            <?php  the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
                        </td>
                        <td style="border:none;height: 45px;">
                            <?php the_title( sprintf( '<h3><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ),'</a></h3>' ); ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>       
                        <td style="border:none"><?php the_excerpt();?></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <?php
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One thing I could do differently to make things easier is just call the "shows" term as it's the same as the "blogs" term which I need.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Hello! Your code is difficult to read, can you edit your question and add proper indenting? Try to keep so that you only do 1 thing per line too. Also, can you clarify what you meant by "if custom field in taxonomy term"? Is this ACF terminology? ( note that ACF specific support is not in scope on this stack, but it's difficult to tell if this is an ACF question or something else )

Comment: Thanks, Tom. I'm new here and can't find an edit button.

Comment: It's underneath the tags, to the left of the box with your name in

Comment: Yes, I used ACF. I presumed WP handles the fields created with it the same as manually-created fields.

Comment: Mostly, but it treats repeater fields very differently, and how and what it stores in those fields can be ACF specific, so a hefty dose of context is needed. Also ACF 4 is very, very different to ACF 5 ( avoid ACF 4 )

Comment: I'm working with ACF 5.7.7.
My first taxonomy term (in "shows") has a field. If I have entered data in that plain text field I'm displaying the HTML and loop in the code above. Excuse me for not being very clear.

Comment: I've edited your code formatting, it's the same code but now it's indented and formatted so things are clearer. Get yourself an editor that will do all of that for you, I use Sublime Text so that when I start a new line it indents automatically to save typing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you got a lot of stuff right, and some things wrong, so I'll go through it line by line

**First**:

```
    wp_reset_query();
```

This function cleans up after a `query_posts` call, you should never use either of them. Sadly, a lot of tutorial writers use this instead of what they intended to use, `wp_reset_postdata`, as it calls that function internally.

To save time, this is what a well formed `WP_Query` that cleans up after itself looks like:

```
$args = array();
$q = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $q->have_posts() ) { // if posts were found
    while( $q->have_posts() { // for each post
        $q->the_post(); // set the current post
        the_title(); // display its title
        the_content(); // display its content
    }
    // after the loop, reset the current post back to before the loop 
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // no posts were found
}
```

Notice that `wp_reset_postdata` is called after the `while` loop, but inside the `if` statement. This way the postdata is only reset if there is work to cleanup.

**Second:**

Your query arguments are close but not quite right:

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'blogs',
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'show-blogs',
                'field' => $news,
                'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
                'posts_per_page' => 2,
            ),
        ),
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Notes:

- `field` identifies what it is you're searching for. AKA the term withe **ID** 5, or the term with the **slug** `test`, etc, it has a limited number of possible values. The default is `term_id`, so you should remove this
- `terms` is right, but you can make things simpler by passing in the term ID instead, aka `'terms' => $custom_term->term_id,`, this might even be a tiny bit faster. Eitherway, always prefer term IDs over term slugs or names, as slugs/names can be edited, but IDs always remain the same
- The extra `posts_per_page` doesn't belong in `tax_query`

**Third:**

Your code is pulling 2 posts as you wanted, it's just doing it multiple times. Instead of 1 query that's misbehaving, it's multiple queries doing the same thing, but for different terms.

```
$custom_terms = get_terms('show-blogs');
foreach ( $custom_terms as $custom_term ) {
```

Lets say that `$custom_terms` contains `5` terms. That's 5 iterations of the loop, and a query for 2 posts in each loop, so 2 posts x 5 iterations = 10 posts.

We can demonstrate this by modifying the start of

```
$custom_terms = get_terms('show-blogs');
foreach ( $custom_terms as $custom_term ) {
    ?><h3>Show Blog: <?php echo esc_html( $custom_term->name ); ?></h3><?php
```

Now we should see each term as a header, followed by 2 posts.

**Notable mentions:**

- Congratulations on using `esc_url`, escaping is a greatly under-appreciated security measure that can do wonders for securing a site. Escape late escape often
- Some CSS grid should make your table layout much simpler/easier to manage
- Avoid putting things like `}` etc on the same line, and indent them, and stick to one style e.g. `while () {}` rather than `while(): endwhile;`, it avoids an entire class of mistakes and bugs, and it's much nicer to read and type

Comment: I feel I would be rude if I didn't directly tell you how appreciative I am of your time and attention. That post was awesome.